# Scala normalize string with extra spaces and new line

Tags: string, scala

I have this `String` that i am read using `Selenium`:

```
val address="\nZONE COFFERCDALD ENGLOS LES GE\nRUE DU HEM\n21542 SDQUEFIN "
```

And i want to compare this `String` to another one:

```
val compareTo ="ZONE COFFERCDALD ENGLOS LES GE RUE DU HEM 21542 SDQUEFIN"
```

So i was thinking to do something like that:

```
val newAddress = address.replace("\n", " ").replace("  ", " ").trim
```

Do you think this would be the best solution ?

Comment: Given your sample, your solutions looks good already.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to trim any extra spaces, Your code doesn't work as you expected when more than 3 spaces in a row appears.

`"aaa     ab     ccc".replace("\n", " ").replace("  ", " ").trim //aaa   ab   ccc`

`address.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")` is probably doing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `address.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")` may be better

Answer (score 1):

To bypass the intricacies of string trailing and formatting characters consider these transformations,

```
val a = address.split("\\W+").filter(_.nonEmpty)
Array(ZONE, COFFERCDALD, ENGLOS, LES, GE, RUE, DU, HEM, 21542, SDQUEFIN)
```

and

```
val c = compareTo.split("\\W+").filter(_.nonEmpty)
Array(ZONE, COFFERCDALD, ENGLOS, LES, GE, RUE, DU, HEM, 21542, SDQUEFIN)
```

We can now compare the transformations for instance like this,

```
a.zip(c).forall(t => t._1 == t._2)
```

**Update** An API based comparison of arrays as commented by @ASpotySpot,

```
a.sameElementsAs(c)
```

Comment: Instead of zip then forall you could use .sameElementsAs. eg. Array(1,3,2).sameElementsAs(Array(1,3,2))

Comment: @ASpotySpot Definte! Thanks.